# Approval Process feature best wording for approve and decline

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, antonyms

I'm a UX designer but not an English native speaker. I'm working on a web interface where some item types required an approval from a 3rd party.
So when the user clicks on a button named 'Approval' he can approve or decline the contract.

My questions are:
What are the best labels for the buttons Approve and Decline? I'm not looking for the perfect antonym but the one that makes more sense.

- Confirm / Deny
- Confirm / Refute
- Approve / Decline
- Approve / Reject

Then, the name of the button to go through the process of approving and declining has the name 'Approval', but this name reflects only the approved option, not the declined one. Is there a better generic word that I can use for this button to reflect both options?

Currently, I'm using 'Approval' or 'Approve/Decline'.

Comment: Can you clarify who’s doing what?  A user ***submits*** a contract for 3rd party approval.  The 3rd party ***Approves*** or ***Denies*** the *request*.  Or ***approves*** or ***Rejects*** the contract.

Comment: A first user submits the contract for approval and then another user should approve or decline it.

Comment: Hard to offer an authoritative answer. I think decline or reject are each a good word to use. Users will not stop to think about any subtle differences.

Comment: *Approvals* is an easy task to understand, though **Review/Approve** is even clearer that clicking is not yet approving. Become friends with a native-speaking Tech Writer or Business Analyst in your firm for wordsmithing now and down the road.

Comment: The button is a verb for the action the user is performing. Your first user is submitting the item for approval or denial. So SUBMIT. The user who receives the item chooses between APPROVE and DENY or ACCEPT and REJECT.

Comment: I suggest this would be better suited somewhere like Writing than here in ELU.

Answer (score 0):

The single button could have **Assess** or **Assessment**

The two buttons could be

- **Accept/Reject** OR **Accept/Not Accept**
- **Approve/Disapprove** OR **Approve/Not Approve**
- **Approve/Nix**